# Difference between WSDL and MEX

Tags: wcf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [All about WSDL vs MEX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763318/all-about-wsdl-vs-mex)

What is difference between getting the service’s metadata by using the WSDL's http get url, and getting the metadata by calling the MEX endpoin

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763318/all-about-wsdl-vs-mex